# How to transform xPath to CSS Selector

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, automation, css-selectors

Can anyone help me transform my xPath to CSS Selector? The code i want to change is this one:

```
String selector = "";
    if(hasBaseCls()){
        selector += " and contains(@class, '" + getBaseCls() + "')";
    }
    if(hasCls()){
        selector += " and contains(@class, '" + getCls() + "')";
    }
    if (hasName()) {
        selector += " and contains(@name,'" + getName() + "')";
    }
    if(hasStyle()){
        selector += " and contains(@style ,'" + getStyle() + "')";
    }

    if(hasVisibleOption()){
        selector += " and count(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@style, 'display: none')]) = 0";
    }
```

I am trying to change my framework to use CSS selectors and this is a typical construction in my code. If i see a valuable answer on this one i think i can manage most of my other constructions

Comment: There is no CSS equivalent for `ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@style, 'display: none')]`.

Comment: i was afraid this answer would come up :( how about the other ones? or maybe a workaround for the ancestor-or-self ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the part of it for:

```
String selector = "";
if(hasBaseCls()){
    selector += "." + getBaseCls();
}
if(hasCls()){
    selector += "." + getCls();
}
if (hasName()) {
    selector += "[name*='" + getName() + "']";
}
if(hasStyle()){
    selector += "[style*='" + getStyle() + "']";
}
```

so selector will be something like `a.class1.class2[name*='somename'][style*='somestyle']`

Comment: thanks, this makes me understand better the css selectors and my life easier in changing all of my xPath expressions